# Is there any alternative available of the "C:\Users\Public\Documents" folder?

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions

I wants to read/write a file in window os which has default rights for the read and write for any user.

Curerunly i am writing in the "C:\Users\Public\Documents" which has read/write file. Due to security reason it is not preferable .

Is there any other alternative available of "C:\Users\Public\Documents"?

Other than %temp%.

Thanks,

Comment: What about %temp%?

Comment: %temp% may delete occasionally. So it is not preferable option.

Comment: What's the question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: The global Program Data folder (typically `C:\ProgramData`) is also world-writable, though unlike the Public Documents folder you might need to explicitly set permissions on any files and directories you create.  But since you haven't mentioned why you don't want to use Public Documents, it's hard to provide good advice.

Comment: @Oscar, `%temp%` is a per-user folder, so presumably not what the OP is looking for.  (Otherwise they'd just use the user's Application Data folder.)